# Is there a way to share local MSDN help accross the network?

Tags: visual-studio, msdn

I'm using Visual Studio and there are some guys that aren't but they would love to use the local help instead of internet help. Quick API searches would save time in the end of the day.

So I tried to download the MSDN library locally and saw that it creates some sort of server that serves only for the localhost, I cannot even use my IP in the browser instead of localhost or 127.0.0.1. Therefore I cannot share the library to others. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doubtful.  If they don't use Visual Studio then it is quite unlikely they'd need the Silverlight, .NET 4.0 and Win7 additions in the current version of the library.  Which make [this download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7bbe5eda-5062-4ebb-83c7-d3c5ff92a373&displaylang=en) still relevant.  Obviously this is not a long-term solution, an MSDN subscription is a pretty essential resource for any professional programmer that works in the MSFT stack.  Avoiding spending the money is a death by thousands of needle pricks of wasted seconds.

Comment: We only need the C# API and most people here uses Mac. Is there an offline C# API to be downloaded somewhere, something that's not an .exe?